# How to make sure validation in adorner layer is shown behind other controls

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, adorner, adornerlayer

I have a WPF application that has user validation. This is rendered in the adorner layer, that appears above all other layers, according to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx#rendering_behavior_for_Adorners).

In the screenshot you can see that this isn't exactly what I want. I have a popup called 'Alert details' which is a [`ChildWindow`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow) from the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/). It is positioned behind the adorner layer. How can I make the popup appear in front of the adorner layer?

I already tried setting a really high [`Panel.ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) on the ChildWindow but that doesn't make a difference.

---

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An [`AdornerDecorator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator.aspx) is used to provide a given [`AdornerLayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.aspx) for a set of controls. By default, this decorator is in the default `Window` template, thus covering all controls in the window.

Add a new `AdornerDecorator` around your form, and make sure the `ChildWindow` comes after it so that it's above the decorator.

```
<Grid>
  <AdornerDecorator>
    ... your summary form ...
  </AdornerDecorator>
  <ChildWindow .. />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Brilliant... did not know about this one, thnx!